# GIT naming my repository

Tags: git

I'm following [this guide](http://progit.org/book/ch4-2.html) where it says to run `$ git clone --bare stef_project stef_project.git`. I get `fatal: repository 'stef_project' does not exist.`

It seems my repo doesn't have a name. In the .git folder there is a `DESCRIPTION` file that contained a default message which I replaced with `stef_project`, now when I run the `clone` command again I still get the same error message.

How can I name or rename my repo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's your current working directory? Suppose it's called "mydir", you can move one directory above and clone like this:

```
cd ..
git clone --bare mydir stef_project.git
```

Comment: That worked. Any idea why editing the DESCRIPTION file didn't seem to (re)name the repo?

Comment: Sharing [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34270097/2404470) for future readers

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I found this worked:

```
D:\AEMS\AEMS Website>git clone --bare "AEMS Website" AEMS_Website.git
fatal: repository 'AEMS Website' does not exist

D:\AEMS\AEMS Website>git clone --bare . AEMS_Website.git
Cloning into bare repository 'AEMS_Website.git'...
done.
```

It looks like the embedded space in the folder name causes a problem that using "." avoids.