# git clone --bare: fatal: repository does not exist

Tags: git, debian

I am using git version 1.7.10.4 on debian Wheezy.

I am trying to create a new repository (according to the 'manual of [git-scm.com](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server))
However everytime I get this fatal error:

```
fatal: repository 'poekoe' does not exist
```

So this is what I type at command line:

```
git clone --bare --progress poekoe poekoe.git
```

I also tried this on a sqeeze distribution and there it works fine. 
(git version on squeeze is: git version 1.7.2.5)

All installed packages on the wheezy distribution are:

```
libcurl4-gnutls-dev
libexpat1-dev
gettext
vim
libz-dev
libssl-dev
git
```

all to get this working.

Does anybody know how to fix this?
I am running the script as root

Comment: And you are in the right current directory? (as in http://stackoverflow.com/q/10092343/6309)

Comment: I am going to have a look. Though the repository does not exist yet. Since this should be the the way to create a new repo I do see my /opt directory is empty maybe this is the reason why?

Comment: Similar issue, but without '--bare', see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53476563/984471

Comment: Side node: I got this because VSCode thought it would be smart and replaced my spaces with `%20`'s; then as a result it was trying to execute a clone of my local file path instead of the repo name...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
git clone --bare --progress poekoe poekoe.git
```

That [`git clone`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) only works if your current directory does contain the repo `poekoe`.

If your current folder is empty, then the error message makes sense.

The [URLs section](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#URLS) recommends using absolute paths:

```
$ git clone --bare -l /home/proj/.git /pub/scm/proj.git
```

---

The [OP Bonifatiusk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1613529/bonifatiusk) reports [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155097/git-clone-bare-fatal-repository-does-not-exist/19159778#comment28342719_19159778) a solution depending on git version:

> I found this:
>
> `git --bare init poekoe.git`: this is indeed different from older versions who will init a new repo using `--bare` with clone.

Comment: oke so thats a difference between older git versions or between debian versions. On squeeze I can type git clone poekoe poekoe.git and although the poekoe directory doesn't exist it will create one. I will try out the absolute paths

Comment: Nope didn't work, with the --bare option you should be able to create a new repository is what I understand from it. What is an other way to create a new repo?

Comment: THANKS! with your help I found this: git --bare init poekoe.git   this is indeed different from older versions who will init a new repo using --bare with clone

Comment: @BonifatiusK Great! I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 5):

Sharing for future readers...

One possibility can be **access rights**. Make sure that you have *at least* read access to your main repository which you're trying to interact with.

On web based git solutions such as [Bucket](https://bitbucket.org/) and [Hub](https://github.com), this issue is unlikely since access permissions is handled by them in many cases.

Answer (score 0):

you get this error(fatal: repository 'pekoe' does not exist) when you don't follow the steps properly in git.

step-1:: install git and config with command

git config --global user.name eg., mack09
     git config --global email

step-2:: the go to Github website create a new repository
step-3:: copy the address from right-hand side      `https://github.com/mack09/repo.git`

step-4:: go to git bash or cmd , create a folder to store all your project
          do go to the folder you created and now you are in created folder.
step-5:: do this
         git clone https://github.com/mack09/repo.git
step-6:: add heart.txt and `git commit-m " message"`
         and git push origin master.
I tried this step it worked so try it and reply whatever the result.