# Git unable pushing to repository

Tags: git

I follow this ruby on rails book: https://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages
and from some reason in the part when I need to run these to commands:

```
$ git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:<username>/sample_app.git
$ git push -u origin --all # pushes up the repo and its refs for the first time
```

I get this error:

```
conq: repository does not exist.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

- I created a repository on Bitbucket name "sample_app"
- I saw this topic: [git: fatal: Could not read from remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509293/git-fatal-could-not-read-from-remote-repository) but I don't think it's the same issue.
- I tried to delete the repository and create a new one and also delete the project and create a new one.
- I work with IDE cloud

All didn't work for me. 
Any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Addition (config):

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@bitbucket.org:XXXX@gmail.com/sample_app.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Comment: Have you initialized git repo on your local ?

Comment: No. The IDE cloud has it by default.

Comment: you are using `ssh` for auth ?

Comment: @user5500724 I think he means did you do a `git init` (and I would add `add` and `commit`) locally?  I see that the tutorial mentions this, but you might want to clarify.

Comment: I uploaded my SSH key to my Bitbucket account if this is what you meant.

Comment: @KeithBennett yes I did it

Comment: i think you should try with https if it succeeds then we have a problem with ssh keys and will resolve that

Comment: What do you mean by "try with https"? I kind of new in this area @MuhammadYawarAli

Comment: `cat .git/config` run this command & post output in your question

Comment: @MuhammadYawarAli done.

Comment: Can you remove `XXXX@gmail.com/`, save file & try again ?

Comment: And also make sure you have read & write access for the repo you want to commit on.

Comment: 1) How do I delete it? 2) Just to make sure, how I can give those permissions? Thanks again! @MuhammadYawarAli

Comment: `sudo nano .git/config` change the text by backspaces, & go to you repo permissions section in bitbucket to assure permissions

Answer (score 1):

2 things need to be done and it's not clear whether or not they are already done:

1) Your public SSH key must be uploaded to your Bitbucket account.

2) You must create the repo on the bitbucket web site. AFAIK there is no way to do that from the command line on a local development machine.

Comment: In your `git remote add` command, did you replace `<username>` with your user name?  The code you posted says <username> and I don't know if that's just because you didn't want to post your user name, or if that was the actual command.

Comment: I just found an identical StackOverflow question.  Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24875756/conq-repository-does-not-exist-fatal-could-not-read-from-remote-repository.

Comment: @user5500724 Was your edit to the question mentioning the other SO post intended to refer to the link I posted? It's a different post.