# git clone is saying the repo does not exist

Tags: git, github

I followed some simple steps found in this

[tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=75_UrC2unv4&feature=youtu.be)

- Forked a repo
- Copied the https `address`
- ran `git clone address`

I am now getting this error

```
git clone https://github.com/hide_name/pr0-underbar.git repo_underbar
Cloning into 'repo_underbar'...
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/hide_name/pr0-underbar.git/' not found
```

What can I do to fix or trouble shoot?

I checked on my github page and the repository is definitely there.

Google Search

https://www.google.com/#q=git+clone+says+repository+not+found

This did not work:

[Git Clone - Repository not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25947059/git-clone-repository-not-found)

Comment: Did you get a login prompt?

Comment: https://github.com/hide shows no repos this moment!

Comment: sorry I was hiding my user name.

Comment: Is the repo private? GitHub will return 404 for private repos unless you provide the proper credentials.

Comment: Side node: I got this because VSCode thought it would be smart and replaced my spaces with `%20`'s; then as a result it was trying to execute a clone of my local file path instead of the repo name...

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue:

I had this error many times, even when the repo and branch exist & I am in the right folder. Today, I could figure finally.

See example:

```
C:\my-repo1>git clone my-branch1
```

> fatal: repository 'my-branch1' does not exist

```
C:\my-repo1>git checkout my-branch1
```

> Switched to a new branch 'my-branch1'
>   Branch 'my-branch1' set up to track remote branch 'my-branch1' from 'origin'.

As you can see, I should use *checkout* instead of *clone*, because I already cloned it & I am in local repo directory correctly.
This happens multiple times because clone and checkout start with the same letter, and you need to get other people code (getting clone of their repo, but they are on same repo, but in a different branch) so just checkout will work.
Obviously, clone a branch (instead of repo) does not mean anything, but we sometimes type it anyway.